# Phase splitting principle of single phase induction motor

Tags: induction, single-phase

How two sinusoidal flux 90 degree out phase creates a rotating flux?

In particular if A = sin(wt) and B = -cos(wt) are two flux produced in a single phase induction motor. Then their resultant would be C = A+B; which is another sinusoidal function. Then how C is rotating?

But if we consider c = A + J*B then it is a rotating flux. In this case why we will put the j here?

Comment: Theoretically, any phase angle is enough to create a rotating flux. For more information on how little you can get by with, look up a shaded pole motor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> *if we consider c = A + J*B then it is a rotating flux. In this case
> why we will put the j here?*

Because the two flux producing pole pairs are physically at 90° to each other as per this [typical example](https://what-when-how.com/electric-motors/single-phase-induction-motors-electric-motor/): -

[image]

Comment: @chaos24 if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification. Hopefully you can counter the silly downvote I got.

Comment: I wanted to upvote, but it says it least 15 reputations are needed. And don’t know why there is a downvote.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer you can accept it.